# What font do the buttons at the top of the page on Netflix use?

Tags: font-identification

I have been working on something that would add some buttons to the Netflix browsing page for easier browsing and would like to know what font the buttons (the "Home", "TV Shows", "Movies", "Recently Added" and "My List" ones) use.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That font was made by Netflix called "Netflix Sans". For websites you can download a plugin for your browser that will let you easily know what fonts are used on the website. I am using Fontface Ninja. You could also inspect the element to view what font is used.

[image: Netflix Sans Image ID]

Comment: So could I load it from the internet or is it a private webfont? @AndrewH

Comment: If you add HTML to the existing page the font should already be available to you. Just set the right font-family. Though it might already have been set as default font for the entire page- have you checked this already?

Comment: @CorvoAttano you would need to get the file for the font and upload it to use it, see [Using custom fonts using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css). I don't know where you could legally get this font. You could use Gotham as that is a similar font and Netflix used to use it.

Comment: @CorvoAttano there are no "private webfonts" since you effectively download the file when you access the webpage. That doesn't mean you can just grab it to use in your own projects, it might be a commercial font or a custom made one that you probably need to buy somewhere (if it's available)